# Powershell does not output execution error

Tags: powershell, error-handling

I am currently trying to setup a docker container to run a gameserver. While running the Gameserver there might be System errors, like this one:

[image: System error]

Because the docker container is obviously headless it is not Showing the errors and just exits, the execution code for the file is this one right now

```
Start-Process -FilePath "./arma3server_x64.exe" -Wait
```

How can I redirect the System Error to be output anywhere? I dont really care whether in the console or to a file in the container but it would be very helpful to debug this. Base Image is mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2022

Comment: `VCOMP120` stands for "**V**isual **C** **O**pen**MP** Runtime **12.0**", which indicates your server application depends on this runtime library. Version 12.0 is the internal version number of Visual Studio 2013, so you should be able to ensure this dependency by installing the [Visual Studio C++ Redistributable Packages for Visual Studio 2013](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40784) on the target system.

Comment: If the program doesn't output error text to the console, powershell won't see it.